# Problem with Boolean Mod

Tags: modifiers

I used the Boolean Mod to create precise shapes, but for some reason one side does not work while the other one does.

[image: Here are the objects that should be erased]

[image: only the left side is applied]

[image] here is the File

Comment: Hello, have you tried the 2 modes (Fast and Exact)? Maybe share your file? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: I added the file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choose *Solver > Fast*, sometimes it works better than the *Exact* mode. Also maybe recalculate the normals of your boolean object (there are flipped normals).

[image]